# Spring Boot Application for War deployment and standalone application

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have to migrate spring MVC web app to Spring boot. The migrated spring boot application should capable of both running as standalone application as well as War deployment. War deployment is working fine but running through spring-boot:run not working .

Spring boot class:

POM XML

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                             http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <artifact.type>deployable</artifact.type>
        <build.number>SNAPSHOT</build.number>
        <start-class>SpringBootConfiguration</start-class>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>

        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <jacoco.version>0.8.2</jacoco.version>

        <argLine></argLine>
        <additionalparam>-Xdoclint:none</additionalparam>

        <spring.version>5.1.4.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <spring.security.version>5.1.3.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
        <pmd.version>3.6</pmd.version>
        <coding-standards.version>0.0.1</coding-standards.version>
        <checkstyle.version>3.0.0</checkstyle.version>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        <log4j.version>2.8.2</log4j.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.25</slf4j.version>

        <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>

        <fasterxml.version>2.9.6</fasterxml.version>
        <fasterxml.jsr310.version>2.9.4</fasterxml.jsr310.version>
    </properties>

    <scm>
        <connection></connection>
        <developerConnection></developerConnection>
        <url></url>
        <tag>HEAD</tag>
    </scm>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j-bom</artifactId>
                <version>2.8.2</version>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
       <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version> 
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jmockit</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmockit</artifactId>
            <version>1.40</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-jcl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${pmd.version}</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${checkstyle.version}</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.8.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>${java.version}</source>
                        <target>${java.version}</target>
                        <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.6</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/classes/abc.properties</packagingExcludes>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>check</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <!--<linkXref>true</linkXref> element is not allowed -->
                    <sourceEncoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</sourceEncoding>
                    <minimumTokens>100</minimumTokens>
                    <targetJdk>${java.version}</targetJdk>
                    <minimumPriority>3</minimumPriority>
                    <failOnViolation>true</failOnViolation>
                    <rulesets>
                        <ruleset>pmd-config.xml</ruleset>
                    </rulesets>
                    <excludeFromFailureFile>exclude-pmd.properties</excludeFromFailureFile>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.tools</groupId>
                        <artifactId>coding-standards</artifactId>
                        <version>${coding-standards.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>check</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>**/abc.properties
                    </excludes>
                    <failsOnError>true</failsOnError>
                    <failOnViolation>true</failOnViolation>
                    <configLocation>checkstyle-config.xml</configLocation>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.tools</groupId>
                        <artifactId>coding-standards</artifactId>
                        <version>${coding-standards.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${jacoco.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.3</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>nexus-snapshots</id>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
            </snapshots>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
            <url>${nexus.snapshots.read}</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>nexus-releases</id>
            <name>releases</name>
            <url>${nexus.releases}</url>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>nexus-snapshots</id>
            <name>snapshots</name>
            <url>${nexus.snapshots}</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>

</project>
```

Spring Boot Application :

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = { "com.test1", "com.test2" })
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class, DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,
    DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class, JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.class })
public class SpringBootConfiguration extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(final SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(SpringBootConfiguration.class);
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootConfiguration.class, args);
    }

}
```

WebMvc Configuration File:

```
 @Configuration
    @EnableTransactionManagement
    @ImportResource({ "classpath:appContext.xml" })
    @Import(SecurityConfiguration.class)
    @ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.test2","com.test1" })
    @PropertySources({
        @PropertySource(name = "abc.properties", value = { "file:${catalina.base:src/test/resources}/conf/abc.properties" }),
        @PropertySource(name = "sql.properties", value = { "file:${catalina.base:src/test/resources}/conf/sql.properties" })
    })
    public class MvcConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

        @Bean
        public RequestContextListener requestContextListener() {
            return new RequestContextListener();
        }

        @Bean
        public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
            final InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
            viewResolver.setPrefix("/");
            viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
            return viewResolver;
        }

        @Override
        public void addViewControllers(final ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
            registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("forward:/index.html");
            registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("adminResources/views/admin");
        }

        @Override
        public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
            registry.addResourceHandler("/adminResources/**").addResourceLocations("/adminResources/");
        }

        @Override
        public void configureDefaultServletHandling(final DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
            configurer.enable();
        }

        @Bean
        public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
            return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
        }

}
```

Security Configuration File:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan("com.test.service")
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    protected CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

    @Override
    @Bean
    protected UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return super.userDetailsService();
    }


    @Bean(name = "siteminderFilter")
    protected RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter siteminderFilter() {
        final RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter requestHeaderAuthenticationFilter = new RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter();
        requestHeaderAuthenticationFilter.setPrincipalRequestHeader("ROLE");
        requestHeaderAuthenticationFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());
        return requestHeaderAuthenticationFilter;
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    protected AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() {
        final List<AuthenticationProvider> providers = new ArrayList<>(1);
        providers.add(preauthAuthProvider());
        return new ProviderManager(providers);
    }

    @Bean(name = "preAuthProvider")
    protected PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider preauthAuthProvider() {
        final PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider provider = new PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider();
        provider.setPreAuthenticatedUserDetailsService(userDetailsServiceWrapper());
        return provider;
    }

    @Bean
    protected UserDetailsByNameServiceWrapper<PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken> userDetailsServiceWrapper() {
        final UserDetailsByNameServiceWrapper<PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken> wrapper = new UserDetailsByNameServiceWrapper<>();
        wrapper.setUserDetailsService(customUserDetailsService);
        return wrapper;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) {

        try {
     //configure method
    }
}
```

Application.Properties:

```
server.port = 8081
spring.thymeleaf.enabled=false
server.contextPath=/
```

All the static resources (JSP /Html /JS) kept under src/main/resources/static/adminResources

After starting the spring boot run The starter log prints the below

```
   .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.0.1.RELEASE)

Jan 25, 2019 11:39:34 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8081"]
Jan 25, 2019 11:39:34 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service [Tomcat]
Jan 25, 2019 11:39:34 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.29
Jan 25, 2019 11:39:34 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin;C:\windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_191/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_191/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_191/lib/amd64;c:\program files (x86)\rsa securid token common;c:\program files\rsa securid token common;c:\program files (x86)\common files\oracle\java\javapath;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\system32\wbem;C:\windows\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\;c:\program files\git\cmd;c:\program files\tortoisegit\bin;c:\program files (x86)\symantec\vip access client\;c:\windows\system32;C:\Program Files\Cloud Foundry;C:\Softwares\eclipse-jee-neon-3-win32-x86_64\eclipse;;.]
Jan 25, 2019 11:39:34 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2019-01-25 11:39:50,651 CONFIG [com.logger] - Log file: C:\mavenrepo1\org\------------
Jan 25, 2019 11:39:55 AM net.jini.discovery.LookupLocatorDiscovery$LocatorReg tryGetProxy
Jan 25, 2019 11:40:15 AM com.sun.jini.mahalo.TxnManagerImpl doInit
INFO:  com.sun.jini.mahalo.TransientMahaloImpl@363a59bf
Jan 25, 2019 11:40:16 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8081"]
Jan 25, 2019 11:40:16 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Jan 25, 2019 11:40:46 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
```

If I login the application, I am getting No mapping found error.
But the same working fine If I deployed the WAR generated by spring boot.

Comment: Post your complete exception log with info log enabled on spring.

Comment: Updated full start up console log

Comment: Looks like you are doing too much things at once. Migrate first to Spring Boot with your existing configuration use `@Import` and `@ImportResource` (the latter for XML configuration). Looks like you have been moving things like JSP around (probably from a folder in WEB-INF). Looks also that you have added additional configuration. So in short don't do all that, remember you have a working application so use that. The only thing you at first want to add is an embedded container using Spring Boot. When that works start optimizing your configuration, don't do everything at once. Take small steps.